# Hashcode for 3D integer coordinates with high spatial coherence

Tags: java, coordinates, hash

this is my first question on these forums : )

I'm writing a coordinate class in Java for a spatial octree voxel system. These coordinates are not floating point coordinates, they are 4D integer indexes into the octree (3 normal dimensions X, Y, Z, and a forth for depth into the tree). The first 3 values are all shorts, the last dimension is a byte. In actual use right now only the first 11 bits of the shorts are used and only 3 bits of the byte, but this could be subject to change.

Now I'm trying to write a 'good' hash function for this class. The problem I'm wrestling with is that the coordinates are often going to be used in highly spatial coherent situations (hope I'm using the right terminology there). What I mean is that often times a coordinate will be hashed along with its immediately adjacent neighbors and other nearby coordinates.

Is there an effective practice to cause these 'near to each other' coordinates to produce significantly different hashcodes?

Answer (score 16):

You are in luck: there is a way to get decent co-ordinate encodings with high spatial coherence using something called a [Z-order curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve).

The trick is to interleave the bits of the different co-ordinate components. So if you have 3 8-bit co-ordinates like:

```
[XXXXXXXX, YYYYYYYY, ZZZZZZZZ]
```

Then the z-curve encoded value would be a single 24-bit value:

```
XYZXYZXYZXYZXYZXYZXYZXYZ
```

You can extend to larger numbers of bits or co-ordinates as required.

This encoding works because co-ordinates which are close in space will have differences mainly in the lower order bits. So by interleaving the co-ordinates, you get the differences focused in the lower-order bits of the encoded value.

An extra interesting property is that the lower bits describe co-ordinates within cubes of space. So the lowest 3 bit address position with 2x2x2 cubes, the lowest 6 bits address position within 4*4*4 cubes, the lowest 9 bits position within 8*8*8 cubes etc. So this is actually a pretty ideal system for addressing co-ordinates within an octree.

Comment: That is ingenious. Thank you very much for making me aware of this, and for the link. I will try implementing this as soon as possible. Thank you again very much.

Answer (score 3):

"Significantly different" really depends on what you're doing with the hash code afterwards. In some cases it will then be subject to a round-robin bucket pick by taking the `hash % size` where `size` is the size of the hash map you're using, for example. Obviously that will change over time. I'd usually use something like:

```
int hash = 23;
hash = hash * 31 + x;
hash = hash * 31 + y;
hash = hash * 31 + z;
hash = hash * 31 + depth;
return hash;
```

(This is cribbed from [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), basically.) Obviously it means that `(x1, y1, z1)` and `(x1 + 1, y1 - 31, z1)` would have the same hash code, but if you're mostly worried about *very* near neighbours it shouldn't be a problem.

EDIT: mikera's answer is likely to work *better* but be more complicated to code. I would personally try this very simple approach first, and see whether it's *good enough* for your actual use cases. Use progressively more effective but complicated approaches until you find one which is good enough.

Comment: I deleted my own similar answer because both your answer and my answer do not have a very good distribution for values skewed toward smaller short values.  Running an analysis on your function for x, y, z inputs to 256 and depth to 16 shows that bit 24 is set with double the frequency of bits 0..23 (which are well-distributed), and bits 25-31 are not set at all, for any input combination.  I'm running a simulation to the full 2^11 input range that the OP describes out of curiosity, but that will take a bit.

Comment: @EricJ.: But we won't really need uniform distribution here, IMO - we just need a pretty small chance of actual collision. I think mikera's answer is likely to be a better one anyway, but I'll leave this up for the moment.

Comment: With 25 used bits and only 10000 inputs (small for 3D model) there's a 77% chance of at least one collision.  With 100,000 points, at least one hash collision is virtually assured.  Assumes this birthday problem calculator is correct http://lazycackle.com/Probability_of_repeated_event_online_calculator__birthday_problem_.html

Comment: Ah yes, funny that you mention this, because it's almost exactly what I have currently implemented (I love that book). This hash performs rather well on a large groups of coordinates and/or on coordinates that are randomly spread about a region, but it's performance is notably less desirable for small clumps of adjacent coordinates. When graphed the coordinates often group into only a couple clumps, resulting in a significant number of collisions. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @EricJ.: It depends on the impact of a collision. If that's disastrous, then sure, this is not the way to go - but usually having one collision isn't actually too bad - it means that very occasionally you take a *little* bit longer to look something up. (Note that this may well be faster for *all* points at computing the hash to start with.)

Comment: @Steven: I'd have expected quite the opposite - unless your clusters are of reasonable size. But it may be worth tweaking this to use a larger multiple, which could significantly improve it for your use case. Bear in mind that the hash computation will need to be performed for *all* insertions and lookups, so a few collisions with a fast algorithm may be better than no collisions with a slower algorithm. Of course, if you can get a fast, simple algorithm with no collisions, that's even better :) My point is really that you should be benchmarking whole performance, not just #collisions.

Comment: @Steven: Not that I'm suggesting you're not already doing that, of course :) It's just we don't know exactly what you *are* doing at the moment, or how much impact the collisions are really having. If the more complex algorithm works better in reality then obviously that's perfectly valid :)

Comment: My initial comment was wrong. I had meant by performing well on large groups was that when the resulting hashes where graphed with a similar algorithm the hashes seemed to spread nicely over a large range of values. Upon closer inspection I realized the values were still clumping into groups, but each point had a small offset from the last and together with the sheer volume it created the appearance of a nice spreard. However, if you took a small group of those points that were near each other and graphed their hashes, it was then clearly revealed they all produced results that clustered.

Comment: @Steven: Oh the results will *cluster*, certainly - but depending on how you're using the hash, that may well not matter at all. Have you managed to find evidence that this is actually causing your app to run slowly? You haven't said what you're doing with these hash codes - are you just using these objects as keys in a `HashMap`? Have you found that you *are* losing performance due to hash collisions?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: That's a good point you bring up. In all likelihood the above hash would serve well enough, but as my application is still in the very early stages of development I can't definitively spot a bottleneck nor am I looking to prematurely optimize. I was just curious what algorithms were out there because I saw a special set of circumstances in this class's hash that differs from the boilerplate approach above; something where the hash 'could be better' but doesn't necessarily need to. I was curious, I enjoy these kinds of puzzles. If only I were better at them.